# Write to file Python, error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I tried to write in file:

```
 f = open('parsed.txt', 'w')

f.write(url + '\n' + title + '\n' + email + '\n\n')
```

But I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brand Cream/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/index.py", line 122, in parsePage
    f = open('parsed.txt', 'w')
TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What is wrong?

Comment: do you happen to have an `open` function of your own in your code?

Comment: you have own function `open()` or you use `from ... import *` and it overwrites oryginal `open()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a function called `open` in an other place of your code which takes only one argument. This is why you get this error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I get empty file, so, I created file in the same directory where I run script